# TypeError: $ is undefined : $.widget("ui.combobox", {

Tags: php, jquery, combobox

I use jquery in comboboxes, and I'm not abele to get the comboboxes in the interface to be displayed. The error in firebug is the following :

TypeError: $ is undefined : $.widget("ui.combobox", {

I'm using the following file jquery.ui.combobox.js:

Code :

```
$.widget("ui.combobox", {
    options: {
        openDialogButtonText: "+",
        dialogHeaderText: "Add option",
        saveButtonImgUrl: null,
        closeButtontext: "Ok"
    },
    _create: function() {
        var selectBox = $(this.element),
            id = selectBox.attr("id"),
            self = this;

        selectBox.addClass("ui-combobox");
        // create HTML to inject in the DOM
        this.addHtml(id, selectBox);
        // turn dialog html into a JQuery UI dialog component
        this.addDialog(id);

        // @todo set proper button height (roughly equal to select height)

        $("#" + id + "-button-opendialog").bind("click", function() {
            $("#" + id + "-editor-dialog").dialog("open");
        }).button();

        $("#" + id + "-button-save").bind("click", function() {            
            self.addOption(id, selectBox);
        }).button();

        this._init();
        return this;
    },
    addHtml: function(id, selectBox) {
        var imgHtml = "";
        if (this.options.saveButtonImgUrl != null) {
            imgHtml = '<img src="' + this.options.saveButtonImgUrl + '" alt="opslaan" />';
        }
        $('&nbsp;<button id="' + id + '-button-opendialog">' +
            this.options.openDialogButtonText +
            '</button>' +
            '<div id="' + id + '-editor-dialog" class="ui-combobox-editor">' +
            '<input id="' + id + '-newitem" type="text" />&nbsp;' +
            ' <button id="' + id + '-button-save">' +
            imgHtml + ' Opslaan' +
            ' </button>' +
            '</div>').insertAfter(selectBox);
    },
    addDialog: function(id) {
        var options = this.options;
        $("#" + id + "-editor-dialog").dialog( {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity:0.5,
                background:"black"
            },
            buttons: {
                // @todo make button text configurable
                "Ok": function() {
                    $("#" + id + "-editor-dialog").dialog("close");
                    return;
                }
            },
            title: options.dialogHeaderText,
            hide: 'fold'
        });
    },
    addOption: function(id, selectBox) {
        var newItem = $("#" + id + "-newitem");
        // @todo do not allow duplicates
        if (newItem !== null && $(newItem).val().length > 0) {
            // @todo iterate over options and get the highest int value
            //var newValue = selectBox.children("option").length + 1;

            var highestInt = 0;
            selectBox.children("option").each(function(i, n) {
                var cInt = parseInt($(n).val());
                if (cInt > highestInt) {
                    highestInt = cInt;
                }
            });
            var newValue = highestInt + 1;

            var newLabel = $(newItem).val();
            selectBox.prepend("<option value='" + newValue + "' selected='selected'>" + newLabel + "</option>");
            this._trigger("addoption", {}, newValue);
            // cleanup and close dialog
            $(newItem).val("");
            $("#" + id + "-editor-dialog").dialog("close");
        } else {
            this._trigger("addoptionerror", {}, "You are required to supply a text");
        }
    },
    _init: function() {
    // called each time .statusbar(etc.) is called
    },
    destroy: function() {
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments); // default destroy
    //        $(".ui-combobox-button").remove();
    //        $(".ui-combobox-editor").remove();
    }
});
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Looks like you don't have jQuery on the page.

Comment: Not seeing PHP on the page either.

Comment: Append this to your head: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` -- However, if your page is NOT online but you're running it locally, insert `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead. Also, you may check in your javascript file if jQuery is running with a comfort alert like such: `if (jQuery) { alert("jQuery loaded"); }`

Answer (score 2):

The message "$ is undefined" means that the function called "$" is not defined anywhere on your page. Thus, when this code is executed, it does not know what to do when this line is encountered.

The $ function is defined by jQuery. Therefore, the message is indicating that it hasn't loaded the jQuery library by the time your code is executed. This could be for a number of things

1. You haven't included the full jQuery library on your page. This may be because you have forgotten to include it or you have only included some extension to jQuery such as jQuery.UI.

   If you are unsure, try adding the following line to the top of your head element in your HTML. Make sure you haven't put any JS before this line:

   `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. You have included jQuery but it is failing to load. This may be because the link you are using is incorrect. Double check by using the [Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) in Firebug.
3. jQuery is included on your page, but you have included your own JS first. This won't work because the $ function won't get defined until jQuery is loaded, but your code will try and execute first. Check the order in which you are including your JS and make sure that jQuery is first.